# Как ограничить размер изображения не более размера блока в котором оно находится?

Tags: html, css

```css
.banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
      <div class="container-fluid p-3 banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      Контент 1
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <img src="https://gudvil.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/image-1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Почему-то изображение вылазит на границы блока **banner**

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

> Почему-то изображение вылазит на границы блока banner

В данном случае, изображение ведет себя предсказуемо, т.к. мы явно не ограничили его размер.
Мы можем указать картинке конкретную высоту, или 100%. В последнем случае, возникает вопрос, 100% относительно чего? Мы должны указать размер родительскому элементу. И тут история повторяется и у нас тот же вопрос, должна быть задана высота, и так далее. Думаю мысль понятна.

В Bootstrap есть [вспомогательные классы](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/) `.w-*`, `.h-*`, `.mw-*`, `.mh-*`.

```css
.banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid banner">
  <div class="row p-3 h-100">
    <div class="col-6">Контент 12</div>
    <div class="col-6 mh-100">
      <img src="https://gudvil.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/image-1.jpg" class="mh-100 mw-100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```